# audio effects tuna library

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm working on an audio recording demo https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder. the user after recording the voice is allowed to add filters to audio.(filters functions found in AudioSequenceEditor.js)I want to add filters to that project using tuna library https://github.com/Dinahmoe/tuna but I  don't know where and how to use them.can please someone show me one filter to see hoow can I use it?.thank you in advance.
note that i'm very new to javascript

Comment: First Google hit for ["tuna example javascript"](https://www.google.com/search?q=tuna+example+javascript) - Example usage of Tuna - http://www.javascriptoo.com/tuna

Comment: Looks like there are some errors on the page but the usage should be the same.

Comment: so you're still helping me?

Comment: if you are still really helping me thanks alot but that doesn't fit the code im using https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder because I don't know where tto put the code because this demo uses a page just for the filter function which doesn't have window.onload and depends on a portion of the audio to apply the filter to.so if still willing to help.hope you help me with this,else thanks anyway